# Вопрос по методу __add__

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет. Познаю Классы в python. Не могу понять реализацию метода **add**. Подскажите пожалуйста какая реализация более верная если между ними вообще есть разница (потому что результат выдают один и тот же)

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def __add__(self, other):
        result = self.number + other.number
        # result = Example(self.number + other.number)
        return result

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.number)

a = Example(20)
b = Example(10)
c = a + b
print(c)
```

Comment: `print(type(c))` явно будет не один и тот же. А что правильнее — ваш личный выбор как создателя этого класса

Comment: В первом случае вы возвращаете число, а во втором объект. Напишите в методе `__str__` что-то вроде `return f'Example({self.number})'` и увидите, в чем различие

Comment: Насчет правильности реализации - это целиком и полностью ваш выбор, однако лично я бы ожидал, что при сложении двух объектов одного класса возвращается тоже объект этого класса, а не какое-то число.

Comment: Спасибо ВСЕМ. Помогли

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очевидно, что есть.
`self.number + other.number` - это число.
`Example(self.number + other.number)` - а это - инстанс твоего класса.

https://ideone.com/CnrZDS

```
class Example:
  def __init__(self, number):
    self.number = number
 
  def __add__(self, other):
    return Example(self.number + other.number)
 
  def __sub__(self, other):
    return self.number - other.number
 
  def doSmth(self):
    print(self.number)
 
a = Example(7)
b = Example(42)
 
c = a + b
d = a - b
 
c.doSmth()
d.doSmth()
```

```
49
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 21, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'doSmth'
```

Answer (score 2):

правильно будет так:

```
result = Example(self.number + other.number)
```

потому что так в `result` будет объект типа `Example`

а так:

```
result = self.number + other.number
```

в `result` будет объект типа `int`

пример:

```
a = Example(20)
b = Example(10)
c = a + b
c = c + Example(5)
print(c)
```

если использовать `result = Example(self.number + other.number)` то все будет нормально, а если `result = self.number + other.number` то будет ошибка:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Example'
```