# В с++ можно перегрузить операторы ввода/вывода(>>/<<), можно ли сделать похожий эффект в питоне?

Tags: python

Я знаю, что в питоне нету таких операторов, есть функции print и input, но есть ли какой то способ сделать такой же эффект, который получается, когда мы в с++ перегружаем эти операторы, если способа нету, то второй вопрос: почему в питоне так сделать нельзя?

Comment: cout вполне можно реализовать: https://ideone.com/n29BcZ . С cin сложнее, потому что в Python нельзя передать ссылку на переменную, только ссылку на объект. Получается, что нужно создать объект, который будет контейнером для получаемых из cin значений, потом из него эти значений получать. Но это не имеет особого практического смысла.

Answer (score 9):

В принципе перегрузить операции битового сдвига можно, но есть проблема с вводом, т.к. в питоне нет `lvalue` в принципе (т.е. нельзя передать в функцию грубо говоря адрес переменной, чтобы этой переменной можно было присвоить значение из функции), поэтому нужно использовать какой-то контейнер для значения:

```
class LValue:
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value


class IO:
    def __lshift__(self, value):
        print(value)

    def __rshift__(self, value):
        value.value = input()


io = IO()

io << 'hello'

a = LValue()

io >> a

print(a.value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Для вывода можно перегрузить приведение к строке через `__str__`.

А вот для ввода я ничего не придумал.

https://ideone.com/Jma0HC

```
class Bear:
  def __str__(self):
    return "Я тучка, тучка, тучка,\nЯ вовсе не медведь!"
    
pooh = Bear()
print(pooh)
```

---

> операторы ввода/вывода(>>/<<)

Во-первых, это операторы битового сдвига, во-вторых, в питоне они есть, но используются только по прямому назначению.

> почему в питоне так сделать нельзя?

1. Потому что перегрузка операторов реализуется другим способом.
2. Потому что нет строгой типизации, а значит выбрать нужную перегрузку на основе кода программы невозможно.
3. Потому что в куче языков решили, что перегрузка операторов им вовсе не нужна.

Comment: Потому что перегрузка операторов реализуется другим способом.

не можете обьяснить, в чем именно разница, просто я с ооп в с++ совсем не знаком?

Comment: Ошибаетесь, в питоне есть перегрузка операторов.

Comment: @Dima, вот таким: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1190227/178988

Comment: @RomanKonoval, так я же сказал, что она реализуется по-другому, а не что её нет.

Comment: Не знаю, что вы имели ввиду, но для меня фраза что "в питоне они [операторы битового сдвига] есть, но используются только по прямому назначению" фактически неверная. Их можно переопределить и с точки зрения пользователя операторов, это ничем не отличается от C++ (каким я его помню). Может ошибаюсь и вы подскажете в чем.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, в этом месте я имел в виду, что их не используют для ввода-вывода. А про возможность перегрузки написано в пункте, помеченном единицей.